# fit() Missing 1 Required Positional 'y'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am practicing a `sklearn` modeling on `load_iris` data. When I initiate `LogisticRegression` from `sklearn.linear_model` I receive an error when I try to fit the data.

Below you may check my code:

```
      from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
      from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 

      logreg = LogisticRegression
      iris = load_iris()

      X = iris.data
      y = iris.target

      logreg.fit(X,y)
```

The code above prints out the following error:

> fit() missing 1 required positional argument y

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You didn't instantiate `LogisticRegression`; you forgot the parentheses:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
```

The error message arises because `logreg.fit(X, y)` can be thought of as syntactic sugar for `LogisticRegression.fit(logreg, X, y)`. Since `logreg` in your code is just another reference to the class, it is interpreting `X` as the required instance of `LogisticRegression` and `y` as the first argument; thus, the second argument does appear to be missing.